# Is there a 'see also' dataset for 2019 DBpedia?

Tags: dbpedia

The [2019-08-30 pre-release](https://databus.dbpedia.org/dbpedia/collections/pre-release-2019-08-30/) has a lot of different dataset, but doesn't seem to have a dataset dedicated to the 'see also'.

I know that the articles inside the see also section are technically pagelinks, but I have no idea how (and if) I can distinguish see-also-pagelinks from the rest from the pagelink dataset (which is called wikilinks).

Would I be able to get the information from the existing dataset, or is there already a dataset for it I don't know?